# Regex to yearid="10287" from a website source code

Tags: java, android, regex

I have this source code of a website and I want select **yearid="10287"** from it using regex. I know I can easily do it with JSoup but I just don't  want to add the library to my project for this sole purpose.

**Facts about *yearid="10287"***

- *yearid* is a constant ie the letters never change.
- The value *10287* varies, it might be 84748 or 746 but it is always a
  number
- *yearid="10287"* appears more than once in the source code but I just
  need a single *yearid="10287"*

Currently I am trying this:

```
\s*[yearid]0-9
```

but it seems not to be working.

**Sample Html**

```
//Skipped the meta and header because I don't need it.
    ...
    <body class="sin" yearid="10287" ezaw='580' ezar='400' style='min-height:200px>
    <div class="ks">
        <div class="wrap">

            <div class="content-right-sidebar-wrap">
                <main class="content">

                    //A lot of unneeded tags

                    <article class="post-1989009 post type-post post" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
                        <header class="post-header">
                            <h1 class="post-title" itemprop="headline">Tyh RGB  Marco to habits gtr</h1>
                            <img src="https://ohniee.com/wp-content/uploads/avatars/1/djsy8933e89ufio8389e8-author-img.jpg" class="avatar user-1-avatar avatar-40 photo" width="40" height="40" alt="Profile photo of Johnnie Adams">

                            <div class="entry-meta" style="padding-top:3px; margin-left: 50px">
                            " Written by "<a href="/authors/johnnie"><span class="entry-author" itemprop="author" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><span class="entry-author-name" itemprop="name">Johnnie Adams</span></span></a> <script>
                            document.write(" on April 23rd, 2002 11:28 PM")</script>" on April 23rd, 2002 11:28 PM  .  "<span class="entry-comments-link"><a href="https://johniee.com/2002/04/thalo-in-American-film-industryk.html#comments">1 Comment</a></span>
                            </div>
                        </header>

                        //A lot of unneeded tags

                       ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex: `/yearid="[0-9]+"/`

http://regexr.com/3dn2j

Comment: Thanks. This fixed it.

Comment: What if  I want to select all the characters except `/yearid="[0-9]+"/`

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt isn't working because `[yearid]` part is matching a single character, which is one of `{y, e, a, r, i, d}`; and the `0-9` part is matching the literal sequence `0-9` (`\d` or `[0-9]` are what you're after there).  Something like `\byearid=\"[0-9]+\"\b` should work.