# Regex to match everything except pattern

Tags: java, regex

I am coming from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064624/regex-to-yearid-10287-from-a-website-source-code). Now what I want is the exact opposite.
I want to match all chracters except this pattern:

```
yearid="[0-9]+"
```

Why do I do that please?

I have tried `(?!yearid="[0-9]+")` but it refuses to match match.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regular expression matching everything except a given regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781554/regular-expression-matching-everything-except-a-given-regular-expression)

Comment: The question is unclear.  Do you want to match: (1) a string that contains NO digits at all; or (2) a string that contains at least one non-digit?  The answer depends on your objectives.

Comment: @JimGarrison I want to capture all the characters in the given string except the one that matches my regex

Answer (score 2):

There are actually two ways to do this. You can use `[^0-9]+` where the `^` negates the term inside the brackets, or `\D+` where `\D` is any non-digit character.

Comment: No need to bracket `\D`. `[\D]+` and `\D+` means the same thing.

Comment: True, I just like having the brackets for readability, but I removed them. They're pretty unnecessary.

Comment: Sorry, please can you show me the full regex? I seem not know where to insert your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`re.sub(r'yearid="[0-9]+"', '', string_to_fix)`

Capture the group like normal, then substitute nothing for it, and return the complete string.

Or, if you want to go the hard way and negate it:

`re.sub(r'(.*?)(?:yearid="[0-9]+")(.*)', '\1\2', string_to_fix)`

This first matches everything lazily `(.*?)`, until it finds the `yearid="XXXX"`, matches that as a noncapturing group `(?:yearid="[0-9]+")`, then matches everything else `(.*)`. Finally, it replaces the original full string with just the 1st and 2nd capture groups, essentially cutting out the section you want.